# Availability data

Tags: database, networking, simulation, p2p

I'm creating a simulator for a large scale P2P-system. In order to make the simulations as good as possible I would like to use data from the real world. I'd like to use this data to simulate each node's behavior (primarily it's availability). Is there any availability-data that has been recorded from large P2P-systems (such as BitTorrent) available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two web-sites that have what I was looking for. http://p2pta.ewi.tudelft.nl/pmwiki/?n=Main.Home and http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/homes/pbg/availability/

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not too sure about other P2P protocols, but here's a stab at answering the question for BitTorrent:*

You should be able to glean some stats from a [BitTorrent tracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_tracker) log, in the case where the tracker was centralised (as opposed to decentralised tracker, or where a decentralised hash table is used).

To wrap your head around the logs, have a look at one of the many log analyzers, like [BitTorrent Tracker Log Analyzer](http://ei.kefro.st/projects/btrackalyzer/).

As for actual data, you can find them all over the web. There's a giant RedHat9 tracker log [here](http://mikel.tlm.unavarra.es/~mikel/bt_pam2004/) ☆, for instance. I'd search Google for "bittorrent tracker log".

☆ The article **Dissecting BitTorrent: Five Months in a Torrent's Lifetime** on that page also looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of appropaching this is to simulate availability mathematically. Availability will follow some [powerlaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) distribution, e.g. the vast majority of nodes are available very rarely and for short periods of time, and a very few nodes are available nearly always over long periods.

Real world networks will of course have many other types of patterns in the data so this is not a perfect simulation, but I figure it's pretty good.